# handling back button

Tags: android, back-button

I have of menu list, on click of list item it goes to an activity containing list of category buttons and on button click it shows different list depending upon which category those group of listview item belong to. 
         menu->buttons->list view

The problem is from list view when I pressed the back button, it goes back to menu. Is there any way to handle so that in stead of menu, by  back button it should go back to list of buttons. 
Thank you...

Comment: do you call finish() in your menu list activity when the user clicks on menu list? Something like this...
Intent intent = new Intent(this, category_button_activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to override the onBackPressed() method like this..

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// do something on back like launch your list of buttons activity.
return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you...I did like you said...but when I press the back button to exit and go to menu,it stays in the same button activity...then have to  add context menu to exit...

Comment: Could you provide more greater detail as to what you are trying to do when the back button is pressed? Possibly some code that you are using with the onBackPressed() method.\